# mysqldbcompare - ERROR: The list of objects differs among database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I'm running:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
# rpm -q mysql-server
mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
#
```

and

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+------------+
| VERSION()  |
+------------+
| 5.1.73-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I'm trying to run `mysqldbcompare` against two `mysql` server and running into following error:

```
$ mysqldbcompare -vvv --server1=XXX:XXX@XXX:3306 --server2=XXX:XXX@XXX:3306 pressflow6:pressflow6
# server1 on XXX: ... connected.
# server2 on XXX: ... connected.
# Checking databases pressflow6 on server1 and pressflow6 on server2
#
ERROR: The list of objects differs among database pressflow6 and pressflow6.
$
```

I just ran `mysqldump` to export it on `server1` and import it to `server2` and I'm able to run it against other database without any issues.

Any ideas why I'm unable to run `mysqldbcompare` successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you have enough permission on both databases to see and select your tables.

You could do a poor's man mysqldbcompare to check that:

```
mysqldump -d -h server1 -u user1 -ppassword1 pressflow6 > objects1.sql
mysqldump -d -h server2 -u user2 -ppassword2 pressflow6 > objects2.sql
diff objects1.sql objects2.sql
```

Comment: I _DO_ have enough permissions on both databases to see and select my tables, as I'm using same permissions to check other database without any issue.

Comment: @alexus What happens when you run it with the -a option?

Comment: i usually run it with `--run-all-tests`, but this time I didn't, so after throwing `--run-all-tests` back in, it works! Thanks!

Comment: `-a` option helped my `mysqldbcompare` progress to show DB content differences, also some annoying test output.  I prefer the poor man's method to avoid horrendously long and ugly table-formatted output for comparisons.  I also removed the `-d`, as I wanted to compare db entries, not just the schema, and added `--skip-extended-insert` to have a more easily readable diff (P4Merge on Mac helps with per-character diffs better than some other programs).  Also, `mysqldump` allowed me to avoid putting the password explicitly on the command line.